# working with workspaces and Pydev in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

im not sure what i did.. but i am working through some tutorials to get up to speed on python, and i started getting this error message... any ideas on how to fix this? from the error, i looked up the message, and it looks like wham i press the run button it is looking for a file that is no longer there.... but I'm not even working on that file anymore... I'm trying to run something different that does not refer to the previous file.

what does work is if i do run as.. but id rather not do that every time. I'm sure there is a setting I'm just not aware of that i messed up.

[image: variable references non-existant resource: ${workspace_loc.......]

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure how exactly you're getting to that point from your explanation, but please take a look at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html to see how to properly run a module inside PyDev.